# How to render 2 pages for 1 req (express js)

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple application, which asks client for incoming data, makes calculations and provides an answer. Calculations performed several seconds by the server, so, all this time client see the data input form and tries to push "send" button several times. Obviously, server handles all these requests. The better way to fix this - is using some "wait" page. But I can't find the way how to render "wait" page first and the final page after calculations.

Unfortunately I cannot use the javascripts at the client side.

```js
app.post('/answer', function (req, res, next) 
{       
  res.render('pleaseWait.jade');
  someLongFunction();
  next(req, res);
}, function(req, res)
{
  res.render('targetPage.jade');
});
```

Such code doesn't work.

Any ideas how to organize the rendering of both pages one-by-one?

Comment: This isn't trivial to implement, it's probably a lot easier to block sending multiple requests from the browser (by disabling the _Send_ button or to track if there is already a calculation being active).

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. I cannot use js at the client's side, so it is not possible to change DOM in browser. Anyway, client doesnt understand what happens after pushing the SEND button. It is a good practice to inform client that his request accepted and processed

Comment: @AndreyErmolovich why don't you just query the server for result of the calculation and do a clientside redirection when finished? there is no DOM manipulation in that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick-and-dirty solution is to render one template, wait for the calculation to finish, and then render the second template and push it through the same response:

```
app.post('/answer', (req, res) => {
  res.render('pleaseWait.jade', (err, html) => {
    res.write(html + '\n');
    setTimeout(() => { // mimick a calculation that takes some time
      res.render('targetPage.jade', { result : 42 }, (err, html) => {
        res.end(html + '\n');
      });
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

The second template would contain a bit of CSS code to hide the "Please wait" message:

```
// pleaseWait.jade
html
  head
  body
    h1.please-wait Please wait for your calculation...

// targetPage.jade
html
  head
    style.
      .please-wait { display: none }
  body
    h1 Done
    p The result of your calculation is #{ result }
```

However, I have to re-iterate that this is quick-and-dirty, since each template will be rendered as a full HTML page (with a surrounding `<html>...</html>`), and you are basically sending the browser a single response with two full pages.

Alternatively, instead of rendering `targetPage.jade` directly, you can write a bit of JS code to redirect to the final results page:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  res.end('<script>window.location.href="/result"</script>');
});
```

Although you would need some method of propagating any calculation results.

Comment: It seems that there is no alternative of JS on the client's side. Thank you for your help!!